# Webpack shimming have warning in intellij

Tags: reactjs, webpack

index.js

```
function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = _.join(['sups2er', 'web3pack'], ' ');
  return element;
}
```

it's working but have alert under wave line in intelliJ

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {

 plugins : [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   _ : 'lodash'
  })
 ]
}
```

but intelliJ say you have problem in index.js '_' -> Referenced UMD global variable

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saJh9.png)

how to make disappear 'Referenced UMD global variable' warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's IntelliJ inspection something changed setting
inspections profile Default IDE anymore warning

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).